# Received memory warning source

Tags: ios, objective-c, didreceivememorywarning, memory-profiling

After getting numerous memory warnings in the console , I tried using the memory profile tool to understand the root cause. But I don't see any strange behavior in memory allocations.

Is there a way to know what exactly is causing the warning?

**Edit:**

Print screen of profiler
Thanks for any guidance

[image]

sorted By "Overall Bytes" and "Created and Still living"

[image]

and added some detail to that:

[image]

and the code detail:

[image]

Comment: Post the memory warnings you receive.

Comment: How much memory do you use? What are the big memory hogs that you see in instruments?

Comment: I sorted by overall Bytes

Comment: I'll add a print screen

Comment: Please sort by Live Bytes and reupload - is it simulator or real device ??

Comment: real device not simulator. The live bytes and overall bytes max were the same row.

Comment: The first thing to do is to tell us whether you're ARC or not.  The second thing to do (especially if not running ARC) is to run Analyzer, and at least understand, if not fix, all the warnings it produces.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single reason for memory warning. First of all you should always profile on real device - never simulator.

Add a profiler gadget called "leaks" to search for memory leaks on profiler while doing profiling.

You can get memory warning depending on a device even at around 10 - 12MB used by your application. Unfortunately there is no official information from Apple how much you can safely use.

In profile check also Total Living bytes. Try optimizing your code with autoreleasepools (if you are doing lot's of object allocation in "for" loops for example.

You can also check in Profile which objects takes most space.

Without real project to play with - it will be really hard to point a problem. Depending if it's a game and how much images you're using - problem may be different.

Comment: what is an autorelease pool? I am using arc, do I still need it

Comment: Autorelease pool has nothing to do with ARC or MRC. Autorelease pool gives a hint for complier when variable can be released. Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: Ok I will look into that.